# Did Tesla calculate the cubic root of the mass of his food before eating?

Tags: nikola-tesla

In an interview reported in the [Sydney Morning Herald today](https://www.smh.com.au/business/companies/why-elon-musk-s-brain-is-different-to-yours-20180911-p502y2.html), [Professor Melissa Schilling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melissa_Schilling) is quoted as saying:

> If we had Tesla on the couch today, he would get a diagnosis of certainly mania, possibly bipolar disorder and obsessive-compulsive disorder - actually, almost certainly obsessive-compulsive disorder, because he had to circle buildings three times before he would go into them, and **he had to divide the mass of his food by its cubic root and wouldn't eat it unless it came to a perfect cubic root**, and he had to wear gloves all the time, wash his hands all the time.

Now, that description doesn't make the process terribly clear, but it sounds urban legendy to me.

I found [another source](https://www.hands-free.co.uk/nikola-tesla-one-worlds-influential-mad-scientists/) which claimed:

> One of his most obvious obsessions was his fixation with the number 3, and all numbers divisible by 3. He would walk around a city block 3 times before entering a building, **work out the cubic root of his meal before eating it** as well as stack 18 napkins before eating.

Do we have any direct reports of such behaviour?

Comment: regarding `unless it came to a perfect cubic root`: most numbers do not have a perfect cubic root (I understand perfect as integer here), so this seems unlikely

Comment: @supinf: I wouldn't focus on the actual mathematics here. It seems to be saying: mass/(mass^1/3) = k^3, where k is an integer, and mass units are left undefined. I doubt that is what Tesla meant, and even if true, it has no meaning anyway.

Comment: @Oddthinking other references say he calculated that "cubic contents" (volume) of food.  That makes much more sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the 15 February 1890 [The Electrical World volume XV](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zc4hAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA106&dq=queer%20notion%20%22He%20would%20also%20calculate%20the%20cubes%20of%20every%20article%20of%20food%20put%20on%20the%20table%20at%20meals%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi75a--lbLdAhUJW60KHdtpCEkQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=queer%20notion%20%22He%20would%20also%20calculate%20the%20cubes%20of%20every%20article%20of%20food%20put%20on%20the%20table%20at%20meals%22&f=false), page 106

> One queer notion he had was to work out everything by three or the powers of three. He would also calculate the cubes of every article of food put on the table at meals

However, in the 1892 book [Experiments with Alternate Currents of High Potential and High Frequency](https://books.google.com/books?id=kNhCQPbYIsgC&pg=PR6&dq=%22nikola%20tesla%22%20%22cube%20roots%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizhdzG9LLdAhVloFkKHSf3CMAQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22nikola%20tesla%22%20%22cube%20roots%22&f=false), written by Tesla himself, the entire biographical article of *Electrical World* is reproduced as an introduction, but omitting the sentence "He would also calculate the cubes of every article of food put on the table at meals..."

Then in his 1919 [My Inventions: The Autobiography of Nikola Tesla](https://archive.org/details/myinventionsauto0000tesl_b5m5/page/14/mode/2up?q=%22divisible%20by%20three%22) he wrote:

I counted the steps in my walks and **calculated the cubical contents of soup plates, coffee cups and pieces of food, otherwise my meal was unenjoyable**.

According to [Tesla, A Man Out Of Time](https://archive.org/stream/TeslaManOutOfTime_374/Tesla-Man-Out-Of-Time_djvu.txt):

> Promptly at eight o’clock a patrician figure in his thirties was shown to
> his regular table in the Palm Room of the Waldorf-Astoria Hotel. Tall
> and slender, elegantly attired, he was the cynosure of all eyes, though
> most diners, mindful of the celebrated inventor’s need for privacy,
> pretended not to stare.
>
> **Eighteen clean linen napkins** were stacked as usual at his
> place. Nikola Tesla could no more have said why he favored numbers
> divisible by three than why he had a morbid fear of germs or, for that
> matter, why he was beset by any of the multitude of other strange
> obsessions that plagued his life.
>
> Abstractedly he began to polish the already sparkling silver
> and crystal, taking up and discarding one square of linen after another
> until a small starched mountain had risen on the serving table. Then,
> as each dish arrived, he **compulsively calculated its cubic contents
> before lifting a bite to his lips**. Otherwise there could be no joy in
> eating.
>
> ...
>
> The editor went his way and Tesla returned his attention to the
> **cubic contents of his dessert course**. He had barely completed his
> calculations when a messenger appeared at his table and handed him
> a note.
>
> ...
>
> In the house caused him acute discomfort. In research, if he dropped
> little squares of paper in a dish filled with liquid, it caused a peculiar
> and awful taste in his mouth. He counted steps when walking,
> **calculated the cubic contents of soup plates, coffee cups, and pieces of
> food**. If he failed to do so his meal was unenjoyable — hence his
> preference for dining alone.

Also, according to the November 1901 [The Junior Munsey](https://books.google.com/books?id=WOUXAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA274&dq=tesla%20%22cubic%20contents%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT3OGUm7PdAhVxp1kKHaY2DjQQ6AEIUDAI#v=onepage&q=tesla%20%22cubic%20contents%22&f=false):

> Whatever meets his eye, a house, a ship, a cloud, a mountain, impels him to a mental calculation of its cubic contents

Comment: I can't imagine what conclusion to draw from the omission.

Comment: @Oddthinking I can't imagine what it even means to cube an article of food.

Comment: @DavePhD I can certainly imagine "cubing" some food, but it mostly involves cube-shaped pieces of food. I'm much more confused at the concept of "cubic contents".

Comment: @KamilDrakari "cubic contents" means volume. Like 100 cubic centimeters.

Comment: @DavePhD Google agrees with you... perhaps I should have gone there first.

Comment: It seems likely the quotes from Tesla, A Man Out of Time regarding his food calculations are sourced from the autobiography above. Twice it states almost verbatim that he had to calculate etc, otherwise the meal was unenjoyable.

Comment: @YouDontSay yes, I just added the autobiography quote yesterday, while the Man out of Time I included 5 years ago.  Since then, Internet Archive deleted Man out of Time.  Even the autobiography link isn't the original 1919 printing.

Answer (score 13):

According to [The Electrical World](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zc4hAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA106&dq=%22One+queer+notion+he+had+was+to+work+out+everything%22):

> One queer notion he had was to work out everything by three or the powers of three. He would also calculate the cubes of every article of food put on the table at meals, and when in the streets would count every pace.

What gives this version of the story some credibility is that it's from 1890. And what stops it from getting *more* credibility is that I don't see any indication of where the information came from. Keep in mind that this part of the story is mentioned before the part where Tesla went to [Carlstatt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karlovac) for high school (although it doesn't mention when the behaviors stopped), while he was 33 when the article was published.

Comment: +1 because it is undoubtably *better* evidence than I found, even if it doesn't settle the matter.