# Did Nikola Tesla say that 3,6,9 are the key to the universe?

Tags: quotes, nikola-tesla

I have seen the following quote at numerous places:

> “If you only knew the magnificence of the 3, 6 and 9, then you would have the key to the universe.”
>
> ~Nikola Tesla

For example, this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnEWOYKgI4o&ab_channel=KnowledgeisPower-GaryLite) with 7.7 million views mentions the quote. Here is a [blog post](https://medium.com/the-ascent/why-tesla-called-3-6-and-9-the-secret-of-the-universe-b308d8b77eb6) about the quote. People even write [books](https://www.google.nl/books/edition/Pi_Time_and_Nikola_Tesla_369/v4U6EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) about it.

At [this website](https://meditativemind.org/nicola-teslas-3-6-9-theory-what-you-need-to-know%EF%BF%BC/), I found something about his private journals:

> Tesla’s Private journals, which were unsealed after his death, included many references to the number 3, 6, and 9. He would often work on problems for extended periods of time, and during these sessions, he would jot down 3, 6, and 9 as a reminder to himself to take a break.

I also found that Tesla might not have been the first to talk about 3,6,9: John Keely (1827-1898) [said](https://celestegray.com/frequency-3-6-9/)

> "The relative frequency of all sympathetic streams is in the ratio 3:6:9. Those whose relative frequencies are 3:9 are mutually attractive, while those having the relation of 6:9 are mutually repellant."

Comment: related: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/42237/did-tesla-calculate-the-cubic-root-of-the-mass-of-his-food-before-eating

Comment: Tesla wrote "All repeated acts or operations I performed had to be divisible by three and if I missed I felt impelled to do it all over again, even if it took hours." https://archive.org/details/myinventionsauto0000tesl_b5m5/page/14/mode/2up?q=%22divisible+by+three%22 but I don't see evidence for the exact OP quote.